# Improving on Chebyshev's inequality with normal approximation

Tags: statistics

This problem comes from Suhov's and Kelbert's Probability and Statistics by Example I, worked example 1.6.2. It's not homework.

Let $Y_n$ be the number of spots shown cumulatively over $n$ throws of a standard six-sided die. The task is to calculate $n$ such that the following is guaranteed:

$\mathbb{P}\left( \left|\frac{Y_n}{n}-3.5\right| > 0.1 \right) \leq 0.1$.

The authors arrive at approximately $n \geq 2920$ using Chebyshev's inequality. I understand this part.

But then they note:

"Observe that using the normal approximation (the De Moivre-Laplace Theorem) yields a better lower bound: $n \geq (1.96 \times 10)^2 35/12 \approx 794.$"

I tried approximating $Y_n$ with a Gaussian in the following way:

$\mathbb{P}\left( \left| \frac{Y_n-3.5n}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \right| > 0.1 \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma} \right) \approx 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{10\sigma}}^{ \frac{\sqrt{n}}{10\sigma}} \mathrm{d}y\ e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} $

but I don't know how to proceed from there and would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a factor $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ in the integral. Anyway, call $\Phi(z)$ the CDF of a $N(0,1)$ r.v., you have to find $n$ such that
$$\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{10\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{\sqrt n}{10\sigma}\right)=2\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{10\sigma}\right)-1\ge 0.9,$$
that is,
$$\Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{10\sigma}\right)\ge0.95.$$
This is equivalent to
$$\frac{\sqrt n}{10\sigma} \ge \Phi^{-1}(0.95)\approx 1.96,$$
so the approximate answer is
$$n\ge 19.6^2 \sigma^2,$$
and the answer is reasonable if the bound for $n$ is large enough to use the normal approximation (it is also necessary to find the value of $\sigma$).

Comment: Thanks! I gave it another go today after a few more exercises which showcased this kind of approximation and arrived at a similar conclusion, except I find that $\Phi^-1(0.95) \approx 1.65$ (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table). Am I reading the table wrong?

Comment: Actually not. I did not went to the table the other day so I made a mistake. You're right. $\Phi^{-1}(0.95)\approx1.65$. It is $\Phi^{-1}(0.975)$ that is $1.96$.

Comment: That's everything sorted then. Thanks again and have a lovely holiday if you celebrate one. :)